# JavaScript alternative for JQuery append() in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to achieve a vanilla js alternative for jQuery append(), as I need it to work in Internet Explorer.

I need to replace $('#id2).append(link);

I have tried add innerHTML and insert into a parentNode, however I get the error 'Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of undefined'

```
  let condition = false;
  let link = '';

  if (condition === true) {

    link = `<li class="list>List</li>`;

    $('#id1').prepend(link);
  }
  else {

    link = `<a id="button">Button</a>`;
    $('#id2').append(link);
  }
```

Markup:

```
<div id="id1">

    <input type="submit" id="id2">

</div>
```

The above code works fine in all browsers except IE11, which is a requirement. I have tried to replace   $('#id2).append(link);   with code below, but get error 'insertBefore' of undefined':

```
    const div = document.querySelectorAll('#id2');
    const newText = document.createElement('div');
    const newText2 = newText.innerHTML = link;
    div.parentNode.insertBefore(newText2, div.nextSibling);
```

Thank you.

Comment: `appendChild`. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: ?? why wouldn't jQuery `.append()` work in Internet Explorer? The whole point of jQuery (antiquated as it may seem now) is to normalize browser capabilities and API quirks.

Comment: You might also want `insertAdjacentHTML`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML.

Comment: I have tried appendChild, but I get an error that the parent is not a 'Node'

Comment: I will try insertAdjacentHTML thanks @shadymoses

Comment: @Marky1298 That simply means that you aren't implementing it correctly. You should edit your question and show the code that isn't working.

Comment: `const newText2 = newText.innerHTML = link;` is nonsense. You must have a reference to a DOM element to use `.appendChild` or `insertBefore`. You are trying it with a string.

Comment: Try the following code ```var el = document.querySelector('#id2');
el.innerHTML += '<a id="button">Button</a>';
```

Comment: @ScottMarcus Ah, I can see now that newtext2 just returns a string. I want to append link after #id2

Comment: @prabhat I do not want to replace #id2 with link, I want to append it after

Comment: You should update your question to show the HTML that you are working with.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The link should be placed after the input in else case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be working with DOM elements, not strings. Then, you can append or prepend as shown here:

```js
// Create and configure DOM elements that will be used:
let a = document.createElement("a");
a.id = "button";
a.textContent = "Button";

let li = document.createElement("li");
li.classList.add("list");
li.textContent = "List";

// Get reference to the node to prepend/append to:
let target = document.getElementById("id1");

let answer = +prompt("1 = prepend, 2 = append");

if (answer === 1) {
   target.parentNode.insertBefore(a, target);
} else {
   target.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="id1">
    <input type="submit" id="id2">
  </div>
  
</body>
```